# CSS Grid Gap Showing While There Are No Gap Rules

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Ok so basically I've made thisbasic grid but when on tablet view between the left and right grid theres a white gap and Idk how to fix it, maybe I've placed my cells in the wrong position or maybe it is a problem with the image because when ever I use devtools the cells are placed in a weird position (even tho the images are in the center where they should be) anyways here is my code

```
<body>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?1" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?2" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?3" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?4" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?5" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?6" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?7" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?8" alt="Image"></div><div class="box-one"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600?9" alt="Image"></div>
</div>
</body>


.box-one {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(9, 100px) / repeat(1, 150px);
  row-gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .box-one {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  .box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(5, 100px) / repeat(2, 150px);
    justify-items: center;
  }
}
```

Every bit of help is more than appreciated Thanks to everyone

Comment: what tablet, did you checked [browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap#browser_compatibility)?

Comment: yeah it works fine without images maybe its only a problem of the images

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: there could be a couple things happening, the image size may be causing this but maybe a solution would be to use grid-column-gap: -5; maybe by adding a negative number in gap it could close the space?